# Como agregar animacion en ngb-accordeon que contiene un *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap, animación

Hola que tal? estoy presentando el siguiente problema.

Tengo un componente en mi proyecto de *Angular* que renderiza un `ngb-accordeon` de la librería de *Bootstrap*. Este sirve para visualizar preguntas frecuentes cargadas de forma dinámica.

Muestro el Componente en cuestión.

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [animation]="true">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of data; index as i">
        <ngb-panel [id]="obj.id">
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                <span>{{obj.title}}</span>
                <span class="card-btn-arrow">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-down small"></i>
                </span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                <div class="content" [innerHTML]="obj.description | safe"></div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
    </ng-container>
</ngb-accordion>
```

El componente funcionar perfectamente, pero no realiza las animaciones. La única forma de que las animaciones funcionen es sacando en `ngFor`. Segun lo que pude observar en consola, al parecer se vuelve a renderizar devuelta el contenido envuelto en `ngb-accordion`.

¿Por que sucede esto?
¿Alguna forma para solucionarlo?

Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos